# How do I use get-template in VMware PowerCLI for multiple directory levels

Tags: vmware, powercli

In my vCenter cluster, I have the following directory structure to store templates

```
Templates
   Project1Templates
      Linux-OS-Template
      Windows-OS-Template
```

What is the syntax for the get-template comdlet to get the template name in the Project1Template sub-folder when scripting?

Comment: You want a list of templates in the Project1Templates folder, or you want to use get-template to retrieve the folder name, or something else? Either way, you may want to check out the [PowerCLI Community](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/server/vsphere/automationtools/powercli) forums, if you haven't already.

Comment: I want get-template to retrieve the template name. I do $aTemplate=get-template <options> and want $aTemplate to have one of the templates in Project1Templates folder as its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per noam's suggestion, here's the answer I got from the PowerCLI community:

```
Get-Folder -Name Templates |
Get-Folder -Name Project1Teamplates |
Get-Template -Name Linux-OS-template
```

Credit to RvdNieuwendijk for the answer: http://communities.vmware.com/message/2225618#2225618

Comment: Consider adding the useful information to the answer rather than simply linking to it. Give credit via the link. Consider how useful this answer would be to future visitors if the link were to stop working.

Answer (score 1):

```
get-folder templates | get-folder Project1Templates | get-template -name Linux-OS-Template
```

Or maybe I'm still fuzzy on the question.